# How to Calculate Month over Month User Retention based on already active users (not based on user signup date)?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, retention

I have a Table which tracks User activity (i-e user started a session at what time ?). This table contains the data from Dec 2018 Till now. I need to calculate monthly retention (not based on signup date) based on user Activity( **i-e In December 2018, 500 users were active. Then, how many of them were active in Jan,Feb,Mar....Till Now?Same activity should be performed for Jan 2019,Feb 2019... till now users**).

I have tried the hard coded way which is to get the users of **Dec 2018 in on Table** and then Get the **Jan 2019 users in other Table** and join both tables based on the user_ids, but for that purpose i have to write a lot of joins. Need a dynamic way to check month over month user retention and for all months after Dec 2018(because the data is available from this month onward).

```
select A.year_month_id,count(distinct A.user_id) as November_Users,count(distinct B.user_id) as December_Retained_Users 
FROM (
        select date_trunc('month', ua.created_at) as monthly,
        ua.user AS user_id
        FROM     user_activity ua
        WHERE    ua.event_type='StartSession'
        and     cast(ua.created_at as date) between cast('20181201' as date) and cast('20181231' as date)
        GROUP BY 1,2
    ) AS A
left Join 
    (
        select date_trunc('month', ua.created_at) as monthly,
        ua.user AS user_id
        FROM     user_activity ua
        WHERE    ua.event_type='StartSession'
        and     cast(ua.created_at as date) between cast('20190101' as date) and cast('20190131' as date)
        GROUP BY 1,2
    ) AS B 
on A.user_id=B.user_id
group by 1
```

**user_activity Table #**

```
id | user | event_type   | created_at
1  | A1   | StartSession | April 29, 2019, 3:59 AM
2  | A2   | StartSession | December 29, 2018, 1:07 AM
3  | A3   | StartSession | December 9, 2018, 4:59 PM
49 | A31  | StartSession | May 25, 2019, 11:59 AM
100| A46  | StartSession | April 29, 2019, 3:56 AM
```

**Expected Output #**

```
Month |Monthly_Active_Users| Jan_Retained|Feb_Retained|Mar_Retained|.......
Dec   | 500                |  300        |  200       | 330
Jan   | 700                |  N/A        |  450       | 410
Feb   | 1000               |  N/A        |  N/A       | 820
Mar   | 920                |  N/A        |  N/A       | N/A
.
.
.
.
Aug   | 100                | N/A         |    N/A     | N/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the job:

```
with t as (
    select distinct user_, to_char(created_at, 'yymm') dt
      from user_activity where event_type = 'StartSession'),
  u as (
    select a.user_, a.dt mth, b.dt dt, count(distinct a.user_) over (partition by a.dt) cnt
      from t a join t b on (a.user_ = b.user_ and b.dt >= a.dt))
select * from u pivot (count(user_) for dt in (1901, 1902, 1903, 1904)) order by mth
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5965458aa94253de09adcb205eb70b5e)</sup>**

I assumed that column `created_at` is `date` datatype. If not, use cast, whatever which works for you. We need this value to be converted in query to `yymm`. Also `user` is reserved word, I used `user_` in my query.

Fill the list in pivot's `in` clause with all months (1901...1908) and in the future add next months. Pivot does not allow for dynamic syntax here, you have to specify them.

How it works:

First - distinct values (user, month) from your table. Then is the most important part - self join which creates tuples of *starting* month and *future* months for each user. Also here I added analytical count which is required as second column in your report. Final pivot just aggregates such prepared data.

Comment: Thank you. Understood the logic and implemented on postgresql. Working Fine. Thanks again.